# What is the best method for merging time lapsed photos? Accessable from python(PIL)

Tags: image-processing, python

I have numerous photos from a still image camera that I would like to merge into one photo to allow for easy spotting of motion or new objects. There is a bit of noise across the photos but not very much movement (Cameras are focused on areas that do not expect much to change).

If you were to merge these photos into one image, what would you use to do it provided the tool or library had to be relatively easy to call from a python script.

I believe this technique is called Image stacking.

**NOTES from comments**

1. I have snapshots taken over time from an IP camera. The jpeg compression can be sett to 100% quality to prevent the noise from overwhelming the information in each picture
2. The camera never moves and the scene is typcially static. I can mark images that have movement or new objects. I would like to stack the images to provide a single glance report of what happend at this site
3. There are multiple challanges. What tool to use with python bindings, how to overcome noise in the jpeg compression, and methods for detecting big changes in the scene (objects)

Comment: This should be on StackOverflow.  It is more of a programming question than a signal processing question.

Comment: How do you want to merge photos? Are you talking about Long shutter photography? You are saying you already have multiple images and you want to create *one* image that would have effect of long shutter photography?

Comment: Do you just want a tool/software to do it? or do you want to know theory?

Comment: I have snapshots taken over time from an IP camera. The jpeg compression can be sett to 100% quality to prevent  the noise from overwhelming the information in each picture

Comment: The camera never moves and the scene is typcially static. I can mark images that have movement or new objects. I would like to stack the images to provide a single glance report of what happend at this site

Comment: There are multiple challanges. What tool to use with python bindings, how to overcome noise in the jpeg compression, and methods for detecting big changes in the scene (objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can [composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) ([more](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#composite)) with the well-known and free [imagemagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick).

Another option, which I have no experience with, is [imagestack](http://code.google.com/p/imagestack/).

Answer (score 1):

Given that `The camera never moves and the scene is typcially static.` you can apply a very simple technique of Temporal averaging.

Assume an image sequence $I_t[x][y]$ where $t$ denotes the time of image I and x,y are the pixel indices.

You can generate a pretty nice Temporal composition by averaging or filtering the Image *NOT* in $x,y$ co-ordination but in $t$ co-ordinate.

For example:

$$ I_{stacked}[x][y] =  {1 \over N } \sum I_t[x][y]*w_t[x][y]  $$

Here $w$ is the filter weigh. As a simplistic case we can keep $w =1 $ which will result in an ordinary averaging.

**Note:** unlike spatial filtering where image tends to get blurred, this operation will keep the image sharpness intact and will also reduce the Noise significantly.

Comment: So, essentially produce an average pixel from all pixels at the same xy coordinate, and optionally provide a weight per time per pixel coordinate.

Comment: Yes. The problem is harder only if camera is moved during capture and you need to compensate for it.